# In Redshift, How to cast current_timestamp to timestamp with UTC timezone?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

This is working:

```
select to_char(current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS OF')
```

But when I am inserting it into a table it is failing with this error:

> 42804: column "load_time" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type text

Answer (score 2):

The `to_char()` function outputs a text string.

If you are trying to insert it into a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` field, then simply refer to:

```
current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```